# HTML5 Video Vs. Flash: CPU Issues

Tags: php, flash, html, video

I'm currently trying to implement a short video (10 seconds, looping) in a web page. Initially, we tried using HTML5 Video tag with .mov (and H.264 as video codec inside). The file size was a couple MB, but the servers we're using were at 99% CPU usage - which is way too high because they're stacked on top of one another and they could burn up if left at that pace for too long.

My question is simply: what is a good way to display a short 10 second looping video inside a web page that limits CPU usage and will keep a descent frame rate? We're exploring the option of good ol' Flash (SWF) files, but wanted to get some input. Thanks!

Zach

Comment: Personally prefer HTML5 to flash.... havent checked about the performance. But in my setup it doesnt take much time to load and play anyvideo.

Comment: The choice between Flash and HTML5 video doesn't really affect the server in any major way. If your server is burning up serving a mov video odds are it will still be burning up serving a Flash video

Comment: I don't understand at all, why is serving up a data file from disk burning up your CPU?  Is this like a 4GB 10 second video clip, even so what is it processing?  Pulling a video file from disk should be taxing on the disk access not on the CPU, is it being re-encoded on the fly for streaming?

Comment: I could understand if this was burning up the client because of lack of a GPU and so the CPU is doing all of the rendering for the video buffer but on the server the only load created by this should be on the disk unless you're doing some encoding on the fly.

Comment: @shaunhusain: They're small server stacks, probably Atom processors or something. I'm not really sure - but from what I've read, .mov is notorious for being taxing on small CPUs during decode. Like you mentioned, there may be no GPU so the CPU is taking the work?

Comment: I concur. No gpu forcing the CPU to encode is creating your overheating CPU but the weird thing here is that a modern processor, even an atom shouldn't spend that much time on a video file of that size, gpu or not. At least that's my view. Perhaps it is attempting to load the file all at once as opposed to streaming it? Even so a ten sec cpl mb clip shouldn't tax a CPU like that. He'll most YouTube videos are of that size and render and server fine on mobile phones with weaker CPUs.

Comment: You may want to check the code, it can't be the mov file burning your cpu. Try to remove it from the webpage, and watch the server load. If it's a dynamical web page, maybe there is something wrong in the php file.

Comment: @Zakman411 I get that decoding the mov file depending on the codec could be taxing, but what I don't understand is why it's being decoded on the server in the first place, shouldn't it be simply streaming the data to the client where the decoding would occur for playback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer as I couldn't fit it into a comment.

As people have pointed out it's strange that the server is causing the problem here. Off the top of my head there are only a couple of reason that I can think of for the server to be doing this;

(1) the server has been directed to further compress specific files when it responds, i.e. there's a setting to gzip .mov files. This could be via your http config file or .htaccess somewhere. If this is the case look in your console at the headers for the received file and check your server config.

(2) Do you have a streaming server installed? Perhaps the quicktime one on darwin/mac, perhaps Red5 or suchlike? There are stream-through bindings which could cause secondary processes to be launched from your http server which can be set but this is pretty unlikely as you'd have to have specially configured these.

Some advice would be not to use the .mov container for the files, you'll generally have better success using .mp4, webm, ogg/ogv than you will with .mov also when encoding through quicktime you can get annoyances where unless you check the box for 'prepare for streaming' or 'fast-start' the files don't play until a lot is downloaded, theres a little command line tool called [qt-faststart](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=0&oq=qt-fast&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=qt-faststart)  which will take these non-progressive files post-compression if so.